# How to fix the whole layout rendering issue in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

I having problem in render whole layout. In Controller new action, if the payslip was created already means, it will show message like already payslip created. otherwise it won't show anything. but it render the whole layout. This will happen when create a first payslip for teacher.

**Controller**

```
def new
      @teacher_payslip = TeacherPayslip.new
      @teacher = Teacher.find(params[:teacher_id])
     if params[:date] and TeacherPayslip.find_by_teacher_id(params[:teacher_id]).present?
        @old_salary_date = TeacherPayslip.where(:teacher_id => params[:teacher_id])
        @new_salary_date = params[:date].to_date
        @b = @new_salary_date.strftime("%b%Y")
        @payslip = Array.new
        @old_salary_date.each do |i|
        a = i.salary_date.strftime("%b%Y")
        @payslip << a
        end
      if @payslip.include?(@b)
        @payslip_detail = TeacherPayslip.where("MONTH(salary_date) = ? and YEAR(salary_date) = ? and teacher_id = ? ",@new_salary_date.month, @new_salary_date.year,params[:teacher_id]).first
        flash[:err] = "Payslip already Created" 
        respond_to do |format|
        format.js
        end
      else
         render nothing: true
      end
    end
  end
```

**teacher_payslip.js**

```
$('body').on("change","#teacher_payslip_salary_date",function(){
  var month = $('#teacher_payslip_salary_date').val();
  var teacher = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&')[0];
  var url = '/teacher_payslips/new?date='+ month +'&'+teacher
  $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'html',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
         $('#payslip').html(data);    
        }
      });
})
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for @teacher_payslip, html: {class: 'form-inline form-horizontal'}, :validate => true do |f|%>
 <div class="tabable well">
      <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active">
              <div class="inputs">
              <h4 class="" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #dcdcdc;">&emsp;<img src="/assets/side_menu/payslip.png" alt="Home" ></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Create Payslip</h4><br/><br/>
              <div class="offset1">
              <div id = "employee_main_info" >
              <h3 style = "margin-left:150px;"><%= @teacher.first_name.capitalize %>&nbsp;(<%= @teacher.teacher_code %>)</h3>
              </div><br/>
              <div class="inputs">
              <%= f.input :teacher_id, as: 'hidden', input_html: {class: '', value: @teacher.id} %>
              <%= f.input :salary_date,as: 'string', input_html: {class: 'datepicker'} %>
              <span id="payslip"></span>
              <%= f.input :basic,label: "BASIC", :as => "string"%>
              <%= f.input :hra, label: "HRA(%)", :as => "string" %>
              <%= f.input :bonus, label: "Bonus(%)", :as => "string" %>
              <%= f.input :pf, label: "PF(%)", :as => "string" %>
              <%= f.input :da, label: "DA(%)", :as => "string" %>
              <%= f.input :special_allowance, label: "Special Allowance", :as => "string" %>
              </div> 
              </div>  
              <div class="form-actions">
              <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-primary error offset1") do %>
              <i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i> Save
              <% end %>
              <%= link_to 'Back', teacher_list_path, class: 'btn btn-inverse animated rotateInDownRight' %>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**new.js.erb**

```
<div class="container">  
<div class="row">  
<div class="span4">  
<div class="alert">  
  <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>  
  <strong><span id="payslips">Payslip Already Created for <%= link_to @payslip_detail.teacher.first_name,payslip_detail_path(id: @payslip_detail.id) %></span></strong> 
</div>  
</div>  
</div>  
</div>
```

it shows error like

[image]

Please help me..

Answer (score 1):

Although I can't see why your `.js.erb` file would render a layout,  you should try using the `:layout => false` call, like this:

```
  def new
          @teacher_payslip = TeacherPayslip.new
          @teacher = Teacher.find(params[:teacher_id])
         if params[:date] and TeacherPayslip.find_by_teacher_id(params[:teacher_id]).present?
            @old_salary_date = TeacherPayslip.where(:teacher_id => params[:teacher_id])
            @new_salary_date = params[:date].to_date
            @b = @new_salary_date.strftime("%b%Y")
            @payslip = Array.new
            @old_salary_date.each do |i|
            a = i.salary_date.strftime("%b%Y")
            @payslip << a
            end
          if @payslip.include?(@b)
            @payslip_detail = TeacherPayslip.where("MONTH(salary_date) = ? and YEAR(salary_date) = ? and teacher_id = ? ",@new_salary_date.month, @new_salary_date.year,params[:teacher_id]).first
            flash[:err] = "Payslip already Created" 
            respond_to do |format|
            format.js { render :layout => false }
            end
          else
             render nothing: true
          end
        end
      end
```

Something else you'll want to take note of is the principle of [`thin controller, fat model`](http://www.sitepoint.com/10-ruby-on-rails-best-practices/). Your controller is full of conditional logic which can easily be put into the model

I'd recommend looking into [class functions](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/), so you can call those functions instead of relying on so many lines of code in the controller action